# Update leaflet-map when user clicks on map and new data is added

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am developing a React app on my Ubuntu 20.4 VM machine in a chrome Version 100.0.4896.127 (Official Build) (64-bit) browser.

For creating the polygons I use `"h3-js"`. [h3-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/h3-js) can only be added via npm as the the core library is transpiled from C using emscripten.

I want to implement the following: When I set a marker I would like to show the hexagon that are in the data array.

Setting the marker works fine. Also adding the data.

I do this the following way:

**Setting the marker**

```
 <MapContainer
        // center={[40.0151, -105.2921]}
        center={[40.7579747, -73.9877313]}
        // @ts-ignore
        // onClick={addMarker}
        zoom={15}
        style={{ height: "90%" }}
        // @ts-ignore
        onZoomEnd={console.log}
      >
        <SetMarker />

        <TileLayer
          url="https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png"
          maxZoom={19}
        />

        {Object.entries(groups).map(([weight, polygons]) => {
          const color = getColor(weight);
          return (
            <Polygon
              key={weight}
              positions={polygons}
              pathOptions={{
                ...baseStyle,
                fillColor: color,
                color: color, // stroke color
                weight: 0 // stroke weight
              }}
            />
          );
        })}
      </MapContainer>
```

The functional component `<SetMarker />`, sets my marker the following:

```
function SetMarker() {
  console.log("set marker");
  const [position, setPosition] = useState(null);

  const map = useMapEvents({
    click(e) {
      setPosition(e.latlng);
    }
  });

  // render hexagon
  if (position !== null) {
    data.pop(); // delete the last element that was added before the click
    data.push([position.lat, position.lng]); // add new element 
  }

  return position === null ? null : (
    <div>
      <Marker position={position}>
        <Popup>You are here</Popup>
      </Marker>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the `data` array are all my coordinates stores that create my hexagons.

However, when clicking the map the marker is set, but the map does not re-render.

I have created the following app:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-map-with-marker-forked-0uexf6

Sorry that I do not use the inbuilt stackoverflow editor as `h3-js` has to be installed via npm and cannot added via a cdn.

How can I update my leaflet map and show the polygon on the location where the user clicked.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: To begin with it seems there are two major issues in your code. Data should be a state variable. Right now you are mutating it resulting in no rerendering.  Polygons right now is an array of arrays of arrays while it should be an array of arrays. You should flatten it. Last but not least while adding a marker you need to somehow connect groups with the updated marker otherwise the new marker position won't be included in the new polygon upon each new marker click. At any case the code should be simplified to be able to get more help.

Answer (score 1):

The component doesn't rerender because react is not tracking the data that you're importing. You can use that data to initialize a react state and use it to render your hexagons.

```
const [mapData, setMapData] = useState(data);
[...mapData].forEach((point) => {
```

and add a new item to that state every time the position changes inside your `SetMarker` component

```
function SetMarker({ setMapData }) {
  ...
  useEffect(() => {
    if (position !== null) {
      setMapData((prevMapData) => [
        ...prevMapData,
        [position.lat, position.lng]
      ]);
    }
  }, [position, setMapData]);
  // render hexagon
  ...
}
```

and don't forget to pass the setter in the component props

```
<SetMarker setMapData={setMapData} />
```

You can see it working here https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-map-with-marker-answer-ycm2u0?file=/Map.js

As an additional note, your code generally does not follow react's good practices about immutability. I'd recommend you revisit the official documentation and adjust your code accordingly. Every time you use an imperative js function like pop, push, or set is a red flag. Personally, learning redux helped me to understand more immutability; Dan's courses in egghead are a good start https://egghead.io/q/resources-by-dan-abramov